# How to manually include external aar package using Gradle for Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been experimenting with the new android build system and I've run into a small issue.  I've compiled my own aar package of ActionBarSherlock which I've called 'actionbarsherlock.aar'.  What I'm trying to do is actually use this aar to build my final APK.  If I include the whole ActionBarSherlock library as an android-library module to my main project using compile project (':actionbarsherlock') I'm able to build successfully without any problems.

But my problem is that I want to provide that dependency as a aar file package MANUALLY just if I would a JAR then I can't seem to figure out how to properly include it into my project.  I've attempted to use the compile configuration but this doesn't seem to work.  I keep on getting cannot find symbol during compile which tells me that the classes.jar from aar package isn't getting included in the classpath.

Does anyone know of the syntax to manually include an aar package as a file?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/actionbarsherlock.aar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "17.0"
}
```

EDIT: So the answer is that it's not currently supported, here's the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863) if you want to track it.

EDIT: Currently as this is still not supported directly the best alternative seems to be the proposed solution from @RanWakshlak

EDIT: Also simpler by using the syntax proposed by @VipulShah

Comment: Consider Vipul Shah's response: it finally worked for me, without local maven repository, as of Android Studio 0.5.8.

Comment: Take a look at my question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31662782/746347

Comment: If you are using Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, this simple Gradle setup worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081429/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols-from-imported-aar-module/50139545#50139545

Comment: it works for me :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67918749

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70849466/8583692).

Comment: this is the simplest way i have seen. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724530/11003597

Answer (score 786, accepted):

**Please follow the steps below to get it working (I tested it up to Android Studio 2.2).**

Let's say you have an `.aar` file in `libs` folder (e.g. `cards.aar`).

Then in app `build.gradle` specify following and click *Sync Project with Gradle files*.

Open Project level `build.gradle` and add `flatDir {dirs("libs")}` like below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
}
```

Open app level `build.gradle` file and add `.aar` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name:'cards', ext:'aar')
}
```

If you are using Kotlin and have a `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name = "cards", ext = "aar")
}
```

If everything goes well, you will see library entry is made in `build` -> exploded-aar.

Also note that if you are importing a `.aar` file from another project that has dependencies you'll need to include these in your `build.gradle`, too.

Comment: @VipulShah where is the libs directory located?

Comment: Maybe it should be advised to put modifications in the app module 'build.gradle' and not in the top folder 'build.gradle'.

Comment: what do I do if I have two aar's: release and debug?  eg. `cards-debug.aar` and `cards-release.aar` ?

Comment: found answer to my question above: instead of the `compile` dependency add two dependencies `debugCompile(name:'cards-debug', ext:'aar')` and `releaseCompile(name:'cards-release', ext:'aar')`

Comment: it's working but i think the First part is on settings **build.gradle** and the bottom part is on app **build.gradle**

Comment: flatDir  is too slow on Android Studio 2.2.3 !!

Comment: Don't be confused with the sample code. First block with `allprojects {...}` goes to the "project" level gradle file, and the second part with `dependencies {...}` should go to "app" level gradle file.

Comment: Is there a recommended approach to distributing a library that contains an aar dependency like this? If I bundle my libraries aar, I'd like it to include this lib dependency such that my library's consumers do not need to download what they would consider a transitive dependency.

Comment: Great answer!  Though I prefer the official way (import .jar or .aar package), I have found this method is the most reliable.  The official method works with some aar packages, but not with others, but this always works. I use     implementation fileTree(include: '*.aar', dir: 'libs') instead of doing it for every aar packages.

Comment: I believe the libs directory goes under the app directory.  I got an error message `Failed to resolve` when I had libs in parallel with the app directory.  But putting libs under app allowed me to compile.

Comment: Please update you answer:
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: How would it looks in Kotlin DSL?

Comment: Failed to resolve: :cards:
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 274):

1. Right click on your project and select **"Open Module Settings"**.

[image: Open module settings]

2. Click the **"+"** button in the top left corner of window to add a new module.

[image: Add new module]

3. Select **"Import .JAR or .AAR Package"** and click the **"Next"** button.

[image: Import AAR]

4. Find the AAR file using the ellipsis button **"..."** beside the "File name" field.

[image: Find AAR file]

5. Keep the app's module selected and click on the **Dependencies** pane to add the new module as a dependency.

[image: Dependencies pane]

6. Use the **"+"** button of the dependencies screen and select **"Module dependency"**.

[image: Add module dependency]

7. Select the module and click **"OK"**.

[image: Choose module]

EDIT: **Module dependency** in screenshot 6 has been removed in Android Studio 4.1. As an alternative add the module dependency to the **build.gradle**.

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':your_module')
}
```

EDIT: The user interface and the work flow have been changed a lot in Android Studio 4.2. The process to add a dependency is very well explained in an official documentation now: [Adding dependencies with the Project Structure Dialog](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-dependencies)

Comment: Best Answer , keep in mind after that make `Alt+B` > clean and rebuild project . Android Studio why you are painful ! I wish to have NetBeans IDE as Android Developer Platform

Comment: It's not the best idea to create a new module every time you just want to add some `aar` lib to your project

Comment: I followed the steps and it works fine.
But I am not able to access the .aar class method in my android class. Error `error: cannot find symbol`
Could you please guide through this.

Comment: `Module Dependency` option has been removed from the pop out menu in latest Android Studio (V4.1)

Comment: As `Module dependency` has been removed in Android Studio 4.1 you have to add the module dependency to the build.gradle. I edited the post and added the new solution.

Comment: Any method that is based on GUI click this and GUI click that is not based on scientific method. This does not work

Comment: import .jar/.aar package is removed from add module in android studio 4.2 and moved to project structure dialog:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-aar-jar-dependency

Comment: @Hani very nice of you to point out that minute change. Other than that, this solution even does very little code line changes, and gets the work done, rather than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 135):

You can reference an aar file from a repository.
A maven is an option, but there is a simpler solution: put the aar file in your libs directory and add a directory repository.

```java
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
    }
```

Then reference the library in the dependency section:

```java
  dependencies {
        implementation 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

You can check out  [Min'an blog post](http://life.nimbco.com/referencing-local-aar-files-with-android-studios-new-gradle-based-build-system/) for more info.

Comment: This works great, and is better than the accepted/higher rated answers because it's simpler and I can include this in version control without adding the file to each developer's local maven repo (if I had to do that, why use Gradle in the first place?) Thanks!

Comment: @ajpolt Probably be recommended to set up a repo server instead (for proprietary deps) so you don't have to put it on dev machines or in your project's lib folder.  If you just have one dependency, throw it out into a maven structured Google code repository (as a temp repo)

Comment: The most important point to note in this answer is mentioning '@aar' at the end of the dependency.

Comment: I suppose this won't work anymore with latest gradle plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-andorid-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp

Comment: This is the one and only answer that includes the simplest form, with all modern syntax, including `implementation` etc. This is copy-paste the solution. Lots of new upvotes incoming because Android Build Gradle Plugin 4.0.0 now throws an error instead of ignoring broken .aar paths

Comment: If you're using a `settings.gradle` file, be sure to use `app/libs` to reference your libs folder one level down

Comment: I failed to make this work, always getting back some flavor of "Failed resolving dependency". The solution by @artiom using a local maven repo worked out great instead (and very quickly)

Answer (score 79):

before(default)

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

just add `'*.aar'` in `include` array.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
```

it works well on Android Studio 3.x.

if you want ignore some library? do like this.

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], exclude: 'test_aar*', dir: 'libs')
debugImplementation files('libs/test_aar-debug.aar')
releaseImplementation files('libs/test_aar-release.aar')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Working fine, this is the way to go if the library is simple. But their is an issue here : 
You need to import all the library imported in your aar file to make it works. 
Import from the aar file are not propagated using this method.

Comment: Or, even simpler: `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.?ar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: @friederbluemle Rather than simpler I would say shorter, and at the same time unspecific, theoretically.

Answer (score 59):

The below approach works with Android studio v0.8.x:

- Save the `aar` file under app module's `libs` folder (eg: `<project>/<app>/libs/myaar.aar`)
- Add the below to build.gradle of your "app" module folder (not your project root build.gradle). Note the name in compile line, it is myaar@aar not myaar.aar.

  ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'package.name.of.your.aar:myaar@aar'
   }

   repositories{
       flatDir{
           dirs 'libs'
       }
   }
  ```
- Click `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: Works perfect on AS 1.0

Comment: In case someone needs it, if gradle works ok but you still can't see classes, restart Android Studio...

Comment: This solution works great in AS2.2 - gradle is amazingly picky on syntax of AAR files it seems.

Comment: Please update or delete, compile is deprecated and there is also this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-andorid-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp

Answer (score 57):

---

### Only One Time set-up & can add future libs without any code change

---

Add below line in app level build.gradle

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
```

Change Project structure from Android to Project.

Navigate to **app->libs** as below

[image]

Then paste **"aar"** in libs folder.

Click on **File** at top left of android studio and click **"Sync Project with Gradle Files"** as below.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: `implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.aar"))))` for kts files

Answer (score 41):

With Android Studio 3.4 and Gradle 5 you can simply do it like this

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/actionbarsherlock.aar')
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer. The dependency is explicit and very simple.

Comment: Agreed on this being the best answer. Instantly worked, was perfect for adding .aar dependencies to a React Native library.

Comment: This throws an error starting with gradle plugin 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-andorid-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp

Comment: @David Sorry, forgot to answer this. Works fine for me.

Comment: @David You can't include aars for building an aar, this is not supported by Google's tooling, there's no way around that.

Comment: The only one that works

Answer (score 22):

Currently referencing a local .aar file is not supported (as confirmed by Xavier Ducrochet)

What you can do instead is set up a local Maven repository (much more simple than it sounds) and reference the .aar from there.

I've written a blogpost detailing how to get it working here:

http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work when the artifact is a snapshot, any idea why ?

Comment: Did you get this working with Eclipse, or Android studio only? With eclipse, "gradle eclipse" adds the aar file to the classpath, but eclipse does not recognize classes within it.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911665/cannot-build-app-when-using-gradle-android-studio-and-local-maven-repo if after following the tutorial your local .aar file is not found (on Gradle 1.9 or above)

Answer (score 21):

I've just succeeded!

1. Copy the **mylib-0.1.aar** file into the **libs/** folder
2. Add these lines to the bottom of **build.gradle** (should be app, not project):

   ```
   repositories {
      flatDir {
          dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.example.lib:mylib:0.1@aar'
   }
   ```
3. So far so good. Here comes the most important point:

Gradle needs to access the network for dependencies unless offline mode is enabled.

Make sure that you have enabled **Offline work** via the checkbox in **Project Structures/Gradle**

-- OR --

Configure the **proxy settings** in order to access the network.

To configure the proxy settings you have to modify the project's **gradle.properties** file, configuring http and https separately as below:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.example.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=example <for NT auth>

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.example.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pass
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=example <for NT auth>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Please update or delete, compile is deprecated and there is also this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878599/error-building-andorid-library-direct-local-aar-file-dependencies-are-not-supp

Answer (score 21):

There are 2 ways:

**The first way**

1. Open your Android Studio and navigate to the `Create New Module` window by `File -> New -> New Module`

[image]

2. Select the `Import .JAR/.AAR Package` item and click the `Next` button
3. Add a dependency in the `build.gradle` file that belongs to your `app` module.

```
    dependencies {
        ...
        implementation project(path: ':your aar lib name')
    }
```

That's all.

**The second way**

1. Create a folder in `libs` directory, such as `aars`.
2. Put your aar lib into the aars folder.
3. Add the code snippet

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs/aars'
    }
}
```

into your `build.gradle` file belongs to the app module.

4. Add a dependency in the `build.gradle` file that belongs to your `app` module.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation (name:'your aar lib name', ext:'aar')
}
```

That's all.

If you can read Chinese, you can check the blog [什么是AAR文件以及如何在Android开发中使用](https://blog.csdn.net/shusheng0007/article/details/79666505)

Comment: this answer was really helpful for me

Comment: When followed first way,  classes inside aar file are not detected in main project, do we need to add any extra config?

Comment: Please update or delete, firs the answers are already posted and second "compile" is deprecated.

Comment: This method no longer works in current Android Studio (2021.2) - the "New Module" workflow does not have the option of importing a JAR/AAR package.

Answer (score 19):

You can add multiple `aar` dependencies with just few lines of code.

Add local `flatDir` repository:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Add every `aar` in `libs` directory to `compile` dependency configuration:

```
fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.aar')
        .each { File file ->
    dependencies.add("compile", [name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, ext: 'aar'])
}
```

Comment: This worked, But how can put a check , if the dependency is already added as a maven dependency then I dont want that aar file needs to be added,

PS: Im using this to write a plugin which automatically adds my aar to the android project and adds dependency in build.gradle

Comment: @Adi If you already have maven dependency then do not put corresponding aar to `libs` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, As I mentioned, adding aar to libs is automated by a Android studio plugin which in developing, So I want to know whether the dependency which the plugin adds to the build.gradle file is already added previously.

Comment: I do not have answer right now. I think it's better to create separate question.

Answer (score 18):

If you use **Gradle Kotlin DSL**, you need to **add a file in your module directory**.

For example: libs/someAndroidArchive.aar

After just write this in your module build.gradle.kts in the dependency block:

```
implementation(files("libs/someAndroidArchive.aar"))
```

Answer (score 16):

#### To manually import AAR files with Android Studio Arctic Fox

Step 1. Open Project Structure
[image]

Step 2. Open Project Structure
[image]

Step 3. Enter file path
[image]

#### DONE!

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately none of the solutions here worked for me (I get unresolved dependencies). What finally worked and is the easiest way IMHO is: Highlight the project name from Android Studio then File -> New Module -> Import JAR or AAR Package. Credit goes to the solution in [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/failed-to-resolve-error-in-android-studio-1-1)

Comment: It should be noted that Android Studio is exceptionally vague in their import wizard. When they state "File Name" in one of the steps, what they are actually asking for is the file's path... Hopefully this message saves others from a headache.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE ANDROID STUDIO 3.4**

1. Go to **File** -> **Project Structure**

[image]

2. **Modules** and click on **+**

[image]

3. Select **Import .aar Package**

[image]

4. Find the .aar route

[image]

5. **Finish** and **Apply**, then verify if package is added

[image]

6. Now in the app module, click on **+** and **Module Dependency**

[image]

7. Check the library package and **Ok**

[image]

8. Verify the added dependency

[image]

9. And the project structure like this

[image]

Comment: this is 17th answer I read that finally added dependency.. eeh

Answer (score 7):

I've also had this problem. This issue report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863 seems to suggest that directly referencing the .AAR file is not supported.

Perhaps the alternative for now is to define the actionbarsherlock library as a Gradle library under the parent directory of your project and reference accordingly.

The syntax is defined here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Referencing-a-Library

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the issue.  Yes I'm aware of how to make this work using Gradle Android Library but this option isn't really optimal for the project I'm working on but thx!

Answer (score 4):

I found this workaround in the Android issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55863#c21

The trick (not a fix) is to isolating your .aar files into a subproject and adding your libs as artifacts:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('somelib.jar'))
artifacts.add("default", file('someaar.aar'))
```

More info:
[Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar-)

Comment: That's right, and here is the example: in https://github.com/textileio/notes/commit/8e4f12d7ebbf7a3407affd1c7a7f24a579f19940 , `compile project(':mobile')` in android/app/build.gradle , `configurations.maybeCreate("default")` in android/mobile/build.gradle , `include ':mobile'` in android/settings.gradle

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have some depencies in my library and when I create an `aar` from it I failed, because of missed depencies, so my solution is to add all depencies from my lib with an `arr` file.

So my project level `build.gradle` looks so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        //add it to be able to add depency to aar-files from libs folder in build.gradle(yoursAppModule)
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle(modile app)` so:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //your project depencies
    ...
    //add lib via aar-depency
    compile(name: 'aarLibFileNameHere', ext: 'aar')
    //add all its internal depencies, as arr don't have it
    ...
}
```

and library `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //here goes library projects dependencies, which you must include
    //in yours build.gradle(modile app) too
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all solution here but none is working, then I realise I made a mistake, I put the `.aar` in wrong folder, as you can see below, I thought I should put in root folder, so I created a `libs` folder there (1 in picture), but inside the app folder, there is already a `libs`, you should put in second `libs`, hope this help those who has same issue as mine:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't really matter, you can specify any path on the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to import AAR file in an application is given in https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency

Click File > New > New Module.
Click Import .JAR/.AAR Package then click Next.
Enter the location of the compiled AAR or JAR file then click Finish.

Please refer the link above for next steps.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on the GUI to add it but do it in build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

There is 1 more way to do this.

Usually the .aar file is not supposed to be directly used like we use a .jar and hence the solutions mentioned above to mention it in libs folder and declaring in gradle can be avoided.

Step 1: **Unpack the .aar file** (You can do this by renaming its extension from ".aar" to ".zip")

Step 2: You will most probably **find the .jar file in the folder** after extraction. Copy this .jar file and paste it in your module/libs folder

Step 3: That's it, now **sync your project** and you should be able to access all classes/methods/ properties from that .jar . You don't need to mention about it's path/name/existence in any gradle file, this is because the gradle build system always looks out for files existing in libs folder while building the project

Answer (score 2):

Just to simplify the answer

If .aar file is locally present then include
`compile project(':project_directory')` in dependencies of build.gradle of your project.

If .aar file present at remote then include
`compile 'com.*********.sdk:project_directory:0.0.1@aar'` in dependencies of build.gradle of your project.

Answer (score 2):

I just simply add these lines:-

in `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
```

after that click on `file-> Sync Project with Gradle files`

NOTE:- `most important don't forget to import .aar file in libs folder`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

1. Put your local libraries (with extension: .jar, .aar, ...) into 'libs' Folder (or another if you want).
2. In build.gradle (app level), add this line into dependences

   *implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')*

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was an issue with how Android Studio environment was configured.

When I updated the `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `JDK Location` to a later Java version (`jdk1.8.0_192.jdk` - for me), everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Windows11, Android Studio Hedgehog, Gradle-JDK: 17.0.7.

1. Create new folder named `mylibs` in the root directory where `app` module is located.
2. Create new folder named `myaarname` inside `mylibs`.
3. Copy your `myaar.aar` into the `mylibs/myaarname` folder.
4. Create new `build.gradle` file in `mylibs/myaarname`. And copy and paste code below into the file:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('myaar.aar'))
```

5. Add new line in the `settings.gradle`:

```
include(":mylibs:myaarname")
```

6. Finally `add` aar into your module:

```
implementation(project.project(":mylibs:myaarname"))
```

PS: the names `mylibs` and `myaarname` are only for demonstration purposes. So, you can pick any suitable names for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

In my case just work when i add "project" to compile:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
   compile project('com.x.x:x:1.0.0')
}
```