# How do I refer an aar file in the gradle.build script?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle

I have an `aar` file, specifically `actionbarsherlock.aar`. Gradle has built it successfully (or so it seems).

How do I refer that `aar` file in my project's `gradle.build` so I can remove the sherlock library dependency and have that `aar` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem (I want to distribute aar and am trying now how some consumer can use it)
Unfortunately, reference to local aar files as it's expected isn't possible yet.

This solution:

```
dependencies{
  compile files("path/to/your.aar")
}
```

just make gradle to include usual files from that archive. It doesn't do megre of xml configs and you are not able to refer compiled java classes.

I'm going to try a workaround: just create a subproject and extract archive there.

Answer (score 1):

Is the aar library built as part of the gradle build which also references the aar library. So are we talking about a multiproject build producing an aar and an apk or are we speaking of seperate single project builds.

In one multiproject build, you should be able to reference the aar in your android-app project by saying:

```
dependencies{
    compile project(:"aarProject")
}
```

for referencing the aar file you just can do

```
dependencies{
    compile files("path/to/your.aar")
}
```

cheers,
René

Comment: My problem is, I have an aar and I want to use it -instead- of referring the library -as a project-.

Comment: http://life.nimblecouchpotatoes.com/referencing-local-aar-files-with-android-studios-new-gradle-based-build-system/