# Cannot build app when using gradle (Android Studio) and local maven repo

Tags: android, git, maven, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to include the library [Slik](https://github.com/afollestad/Silk) and [Cards-UI](https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI) in my app, I'm using android studio and gradle to build. The app builds fine without this but adding the dependency make the build fail. Looking at the debug log of the build it doesn't seem to be looking in the local repo for the arr file. I can see the files are there and I have followed the tutorial on the github wiki page for the install and that works fine. The error is:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':climbtrack'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':climbtrack:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.afollestad.cardsui:library:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         ClimbTrack:climbtrack:unspecified
   > Could not find com.afollestad.silk:library:1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         ClimbTrack:climbtrack:unspecified
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.afollestad.cardsui:library:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.afollestad.silk:library:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

The google play services dependency works fine and is found from the maven central repo as expected.
Any ideas anyone?
Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63908

If you look at comment #3 in that bug, there's a workaround. Try it and see if it helps:

> This appears to be a bug in Gradle 1.9 with local Maven repositories.
>
> See https://plus.google.com/109385828142935151413/posts/hF7W59uZ7rX
>
> The workaround for now is to use

```
 maven {   url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository" }
```

> instead of mavenLocal()

Comment: Thanks, that exact line didn't work but specifying the path manually in the same way did. eg `maven {url "C:/Users/user/.m2/repository" }`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio 0.4.6 using mavenLocal works fine:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Check and configure your Maven installation on Preferences >> Maven to ensure it points to your local repository.

I hope this update helps newcomers.