# Custom View in a local aar library not accessible?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, aar

I have a local aar file containing a custom View class (including a res/values/attrs.xml file).

I am aware that local aars don't work by default yet, and I have tried all the workarounds suggested here: [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst) (the Ran and Vipul answers).

However none of these solutions seem to pick up the custom View class.  By that I mean it doesn't appear under "Custom View" in the layout editor.

Should this work? Or is there some additional gradle-fu voodoo required?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is super old I'm gonna give my two cents on it.

In my case, I had a custom view that inherits the `RecyclerView` class in the library project but could not access it from the project layout file.

It turned out that I had to add the recycler view dependency (or the `com.android.support:design`) in the project Gradle even though it was included in the library.