# Fragmentation in Android Studio version on include aar external Dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Many of the Android App Dev almost shifted to Android Studio which makes Dev life much more easier but few features works fine in one version will not work on another version but in next version it will work fine !

I'm talking about including aar external Dependency

See this comments:

[image]

Ref: **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst#comment46007710_23326397)**

There are different ways to import an arr file but we need to tryout all methods find the solution for the version you are using !

Answer (score 0):

I Found easy working solution for **Android Studio 1.1.0** (not sure It works on other versions)

Simply add new module--> select AAR/JAR type

[image]

[image]

select the required .arr file, give the name or folder otherwise it will select same file name to folder name!

[image]

In above image shows if you shift from Android mode to project mode you can observe new lib module added which contains arr file!

and finally add   `compile project(':ndlib')` to app gradle

Solutions that **not** worked:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aar'
        }
    }


dependencies {
    compile(name:'myLibrary', ext:'aar')
}
```