# Android Studio: including AAR library from a library project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, aar

In my Android Studio project I have two subprojects/modules: an Android application (`App1`) and an Android library project (`LibraryProject1`). `App1` depends on `LibraryProject1`. So far so good.

However, `LibraryProject1`, in turn, needs to import an AAR library to work properly.

So my Configuration is as follows:
`App1` includes `LibraryProject1`
`LibraryProject1` includes `dependency.aar`

Now, to include `dependecy.aar` I use the method detailed here:

[How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

So basically in my `build.gradle` for `LibraryProject1` I have:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (name:'dependency', ext:'aar') //my AAR dependency
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Obviously, I put my dependency.aar file in the libs directory of LibraryProject1

However, this doesn't work. It seems that the repository added by `LibraryProject1` is completely ignored and the local "libs" folder is not included as a repository, causing compilation to fail.

If I add the repository from the `App1`'s `build.gradle` it works, but I don't want to do that, it's `LibraryProject1` that needs the AAR file, not `App1`.

How can I do this??

Comment: Well, I think this provide better option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32071825/include-aar-dependency-in-android-library-project?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a way, but since it's very "hacky" I'll leave the question open, in case anyone comes up with a better, "proper" solution.

Basically the problem is that the `flatDir` repository is ignored at compilation time if included from `LibraryProject1`'s build.gradle script, so what I do is I use `App1`'s build.gradle to "inject" the flatDir repository in `LibraryProject1`. Something like this:

```
//App1 build.gradle
dependencies {
    //get libraryproject1 Project object
    Project p = project(':libraryproject1')

    //inject repository
    repositories{
        flatDir {
            dirs p.projectDir.absolutePath + '/libs'
        }
    }

    //include libraryproject1
    compile p
}
```

This effectively allows `LibraryProject1` to include the external AAR library without having `App1` include it. It's hacky but it works. Note that you still have to put:

```
//LibraryProject1 build.gradle
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs './libs'
    }
}
```

inside `LibraryProject1`'s build.gradle otherwise, even if the project itself would compile fine, the IDE wouldn't recognize the types included in the AAR library. Note that the `./` in the path also seems to be important, without it the IDE still doesn't recognized the types.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but due to some reasons I have to create AAR file of my library project. How I can add those files into my lib project AAR?

Comment: If you are using Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, this simple Gradle setup worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081429/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols-from-imported-aar-module/50139545#50139545

Answer (score 0):

I faced to the same issue, and I figure out it by putting all libraries on that depends LibraryProject1 in LibraryProject1/libs as a .jar.
I think that aar library cannot be linked to another aar library.
Hope that help you,
Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately, the AAR I'm using is precompiled, and I have to use that. Plus, it's an Android library, so couldn't be converted to JAR anyway.