# Include AAR dependency in Android Library Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aar

In my Android Studio Gradle project I use several libraries, whereas one library should use a local AAR file as dependency. I used the popular solution to include the AAR file as dependency into my library project:

```
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}

compile(name: 'aar-library', ext: 'aar')
```

When I now try to sync I get the error message

> Failed to resolve: dependency 'aar-library'

in my main project even though I'm not using / referencing the AAR file there. If I just copy the AAR file into the libs folder of my main project too it works. Any idea?

Comment: is aar-library the filename?

Comment: Yes it's the file name without the file extension

Answer (score 16):

Already found the solution. It looks like the AAR dependencies are all moved together, so the main project tries to resolve AAR dependency in its 'libs' directory, where it obviously does not exist.
What you need to do is define more accurately where each module that depends on the library with the AAR file can find it relative to its path, e.g.

`dirs project(':my-library-project').file('libs')`

Comment: you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: never would have figured this out

Comment: where to add this? in the Main project gradle or the library's gradle? and where in gradle

Answer (score 0):

I had it working like this:

```
compile 'com.example.lib:lib_name:1.0.0@aar'
```

In this example `lib_name:1.0.0.aar` is file name.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add my AAR file to my library project. I had to add this to the gradle of my library project

```
implementation(files("libs/sublibrary.aar"))
```

where my 'libs' folder is located at myLibraryName/libs.

I also had to add the following to the gradle of my Main project

```
implementation(files("../myLibraryName/libs/sublibrary.aar"))
```

Then I synced and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In case the answer by user1033552 doesn't work. In my case, it didn't work.

Below steps worked for me.

1. Right click project -> New -> Module -> Import aar package -> select
   file and import it.
2. In **settings.gradle**, Make dependent is after dependency.For
   example `include ':imported-aar', ':your-library', ':app'`
3. Now **build.gradle** of *your-library* add `compile project(':imported-aar')`