# Android Studio import module cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using latest Android Studio version (2.3.1) and I imported a library to my android studio project.

But when I want to import classes :

```
import com.mehdikarimi.PauseResumeAudioRecorder;
```

returned error :

**Cannot Resolve Symbol Module1**

Is any suggestion to resolve this error?

Comment: what do you mean by import namespace ?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Have you injected required jars as dependency for the same

Comment: Yes. Is it not jar(s). I'm imported my module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081429/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols-from-imported-aar-module/50139545#50139545

Answer (score 3):

Check `settings.gradle` file, Is your module included there.

like `include 'abc', 'xyz'`

If yes try to `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, but my library added to settings.gradle. (include ':app', ':library', ':audiorecordlibrary') I tried Invalidate Caches/Restart but not resolved

Comment: `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and refresh dependency

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols

Comment: I tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols) solutions later :(

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem first Invalidate Caches/Restart and closed Android Studio and deleted *.iml files and .idea folder then I added

```
    compile project(path: ':audiorecordlibrary');
```

To app dependencies