# How to use an AAR file with Android Studio 1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

**EDIT:**

When I use  the response of [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst) I have an error.

**BASE:**
I never use AAR file, with the release of Android Studio we can use it.

But I don't find any explanation to use it.

Do you know how to use it?

It's necessary to make some things like ask for the permissions or create the dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

Comment: This is for Android Studio 0.5.8. Maybe they have a better solution now?

Comment: I'm using this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/23326397/1377145, working good enough.

Comment: Android Studio 1.2 (stable, official IDE) is out now and the same solution works since 0.5.8...

Comment: You say "when I use the response of... I have an error". Which is?..

Answer (score 0):

AAR format is a jar file containing a compiled Android Library project.  [Here's some info on what is inside an AAR file](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)

What this means for app developers is that instead of ([the old way](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)):

1. Downloading the source code of a library project
2. Building it in eclipse
3. Setting your application project to depend on the local library project

You can instead add the dependency specification to your project/app/build.gradle's dependencies block: `compile 'fr.baloomba:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2'`

Then gradle (on the next build) searches for the aar file in a central binary repository, downloads the library and allows you to use it's functionality in your project. ( ex: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=fr/baloomba/viewpagerindicator/2.4.2/viewpagerindicator-2.4.2.aar )

You can also search [the central repository's web interface](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cp%3A%22aar%22) for libraries to depend on. Once you've clicked on a library to add to the project, click "Gradle/Grails" under "Dependency Information" to copy the line to add to build.gradle.

In my opinion this is a *huge* improvement.

You don't need to add any permissions to the app, either way, adding a Library project dependency is a compile time thing, not runtime or user-facing.