# How do I add an 'aar' to my existing android project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a `aar` module by the name of `app-debug.aar`. I need to add this in my existing android project. I am using Android Studio 1.2.2. I have tried lot of approaches which were suggested like these

[How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

When I am trying to use the answers in this post, I mostly come across this issue

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processIcanpayDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/Shaik/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And when I seacrched for that i came to know that I had to add

```
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

But still I get the same error and I am not successful in adding the `aar` module to my project. Can anyone let me know how can I achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (works for me): http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/05/18/reference-a-local-aar-in-your-android-project/