# Not able to load an aar dependency from a standard Java library module

Tags: java, android, rx-java, aar, rx-android

For one of my Android projects, I decided to take as much functionality out in a standard Java library module, as possible. One of my dependencies is rxAndroid which depends on rxJava. I noticed that the rxJava classes load normally by Gradle, but the rxAndroid-specific ones do not. The reason, I assume is that rxAndroid uses aar, and my library module uses only the java plugin, i.e. it does not know how to unpack it.

What would be a way around this? If no clean way is possible, I would simply take the Android-specific rxAndroid back in the main app, and my library will rely only on rxJava.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? ADT or Studio?

Comment: The latest version of Android Studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst