# use android project as library for another android project

Tags: android

1) i would like to use android project as library to another project . i have created the .aar file from the library project. and extract it to get classes.jar file.

2) i use the jar file in libs folder and compile it in build.gradle file.

3)

```
// call to library project activity class     
<activity
    android:name="com.magento.MainActivity"></activity>
```

4) i woluld like to call these mainactivity.it crash the app.due to not registered acitvity in manifeast file

5) for the i find to use mainfeast merger in properties file.but not able to find that one in android studio

can anybody help on this?

here i suffered new issues kindly help on this

```
Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:29:9-52
    is also present at [com.elitesalonapp.aar:emc:] AndroidManifest.xml:48:9-57 value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-159:19 to override.

    Attribute meta-data#com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId@value value=(@string/facebook_app_id) from AndroidManifest.xml:33:13-52
    is also present at [com.elitesalonapp.aar:emc:] AndroidManifest.xml:60:13-43 value=(@string/app_id).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:31:9-33:55 to override.
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst

Comment: you have declared dependency in your main project,in gradel as module.

Comment: why did you create jar from aar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AAR is the proper dependency artifact for an Android Library project.  It contains the manifest entries, resources, assets, and code that should be imported into the app.

When you pulled the jar out of the aar, you also removed the ability for the Android build tools to pull in any manifest entries, resources, and assets that may have been included in the aar.  Instead of extracting a jar, you should depend on the aar and let the Android tools merge everything into the app.  [You can read about aar here.](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)

Comment: where to add arr file...it is to add inside libs folder right?

Comment: You can put the aar file anywhere you want within the project structure, but inside libs is probably the best place.

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: :emc:
error  in build.gradle file...where emc is the .aar file

Comment: this is how i add     compile(name:'emc', ext:'aar') in build.gradle

Comment: got merging error for facebook app id...i have two facebook login one in my application and another in my library application how to resolve this issue ...help on this man

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** 
File -> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR and import your .AAR.

add following in `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'abc', ext:'aar')
}
```

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: :emc:
error  in build.gradle file...where emc is the .aar file

Comment: @MobileTeam  build.gradle should be app, not project. have you added accordingly?

Comment: hi not able to add dependency ...not to able to find .aar file in

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tba6fvulm92hon0/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-29%2013%3A39%3A07.png?dl=0

Comment: find the screen shot

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wu66ig3hoai04ga/Screenshot%20from%202016-03-29%2013%3A42%3A02.png?dl=0

Comment: help on this ..im struck with that one

Comment: @MobileTeam  If you are not able to add library dependency why this line `compile(name:'emc', ext:'aar')` coming up?

Comment: why that dialog is coming up in this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnrowrmeif5s643/3.png?dl=0 ?

Comment: @MobileTeam look again for edit, for AAR file i got new solution.

Answer (score 0):

add this in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'<your lib name>',ext:'aar')
}
repositories{
flatDir{
    //add the dir where your .arr lib in
    dirs '<folder name>'
}
```

[**look the sample here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znkUe.jpg)

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: :emc:
error  in build.gradle file...where emc is the .aar file

Comment: this is how i add     compile(name:'emc', ext:'aar') in build.gradle