# android studio build error : firewall blocking gradle access to studio

Tags: android, gradle, firewall

My firewall is not letting me access the the gradle . is there a way around this?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication3'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :MyApplication3:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
  >   Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
final def extension = android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tataelxsi.snigdha.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguardandroid.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
extension
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Gradle file ?

Comment: Have your Network firewall allowed https://jcenter.bintray.com  or download permission to this website. You can simply test by hitting link inside browser.

Comment: We need your `Build.Gradle` file here.

Comment: my firewall does not allow this website . is there a way around to this problem apart from changing the firewall settings?

Comment: ive added the gradle file. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You just open your root gradle file and then set your class path in dependencies block like this but be sure that class path set in your project gradle file not in your modual gradle file i hope this will help you

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: my firewall is blocking the url. cannot use this method. i have downloaded the gradle 1.5.0 . how do i add it manually??

Comment: i don't know more about but you just go to C:/User/.../ .gradle / wrapper /dists folder and paste it your folder and then clean your project and set your path or else follow this line        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Choose System and Security
3. You will see Windows Firewall option choose -> Allow a Program  through Windows Firewall

[image: image here]

Now uncheck the Android Studio and click OK