# Update OpenTok SDK in Android Application

Tags: android, opentok, aar, tokbox

I have a currently running Android application which uses OpenTok SDK version 2.8.
that is `'opentok-android-sdk-2.5.0.jar'`.

Due to some known issue, i have to update it to the latest version of OpenTok that is `opentok-android-sdk-2.8.1`.

In the previous version of the OpenTok SDK, there used to be one `*.jar` file and two `*.so` files.
However, in this version the `*.jar` and `*.so` files have been replaced by a single `*.aar` file.

**What i tried:**
I  removed both `*.so` files fron `JNILibs` directory and the `*.jar` file from the `libs` directory of the project structure. Further i removed the below line from gradle.build of apps:

```
compile files('libs/opentok-android-sdk-2.5.0.jar')
```

As specified in the below link, under the read me section:

https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples

I added the below two lines in my gradle.build under app in th respective positions:
That is, under 'repositories' i added:

```
maven { url  "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven" }
```

And then under 'dependencies' i added:

```
compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.8.+'
```

And then when i `Sync` my project, i get the below error:

```
Error:(61, 13) Failed to resolve: com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.8.+
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Further i also tried:

[How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

But i was still getting errors like only jar files can be added like that.

I also tried:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpuJPoXkFG4

If anyone has upgraded from any `*.jar` library to `*.aar` library, kindly specify the procedure here or send me a reference for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm building an ionic app using the https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok

I managed to upgrade the android sdk to 2.8.1 by creating the following build-extras.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "http://tokbox.bintray.com/maven"
        }
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.7.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.8.1+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

This might help you out. in my plugin.xml I also added this line in my android platform section

```
<framework src="build-extras.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

as suggested by https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#extending-buildgradle

However this didn't seem to copy the file correctly, so I had to manually place build-extras.gradle in my ./platforms/android  directly (same directory as my build.gradle)

Hope this helps.