# Sweet Alert Dialog No resource identifier found for attribute 'progressIndeterminate' in package

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I tried adding [Sweet Alert Dialog](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog) to my project using [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919810/2101822) and I face no error during adding the `.aar` library locally.

Sweet Alert Dialog is successfully added to the project and I can use It's classes in my project. (Android studio recognizes it's classes). But when I try to build the project I get this error:

```
Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'progressIndeterminate' in package 'com.mypackagename'
```

I found the same Issue [here](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/91) with no answer. Can anybody help?

Comment: It's old repository. And I guess it has some conflict with newer version of AppCompat. download library and update resource file.

Comment: @Amir guess I found the problem, Sweet alert uses another library that I had forgotten to add to my project. I'm trying to add it right now ;)