# What to do with "library-debug.aar" & "library-release.aar"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I exported the project from Eclipse. Then built the project. There were 4 folders.

[image: There were 4 folders]

Then from the documentation and Google, I realized that I need to do something with the aar files. But how to build an APK I do not understand!

Please explain what I need to do to build APK!

[image: What to do with these files to build the APK.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your library-release.aar as a module :

Go into File->New->New module : choose import new .AAR package

[image]

Then point to your library-release.aar.

After that go into :

File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies -> press the bottom "+" -> choose module dependency and choose your library

[image]

You should have a `compile project('library-release')` added to your main build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them into your project in order to successfully build .apk file of project.

See third answer on this link: [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)