# Android NDK - Execution failed for task ndkBuild

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

Well here is the [source code](https://github.com/routerkeygen/routerkeygenAndroid) of a project (**Router Keygen**) that i am trying  to debug on my device. Unfortunately, when i run it i get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':routerKeygen:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Show many posts. I can't understand whether ndk is correctly installed (on my computer) or not. I just want to know if there is anyone who tried Router keygen and had the same error like me. **If not**, should i try to move ndk somewhere else?

Comment: You can try building the project at the backhand using the cmd-'ndk-build'. Maybe then you can get a proper insight of your build failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if that's good. I went to

**C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd**

directory and for the `ndk-build.cmd` i press

Right-Click> Edit and change the cmd file from:

```
@echo off
%~dp0\build\ndk-build.cmd %*
```

to

```
@echo off
```

THAT **works** for me

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded and it build successfully.
Building on Android Studio 2.2.2. Studio will ask to update gradle click update.

```
Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 12.1.2977051
```

Comment: It's running on Nexus 5. If you are facing any issue then compile modules and import .aar of that module to your proj. check out this link for importing aar library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst