# How to add MapCircle in HERE Map android

Tags: android, here-api

I have added a marker in HERE map like below code.

```
hereMap.addMapObject(new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(lat, longi),setMapMarkerImage(R.drawable.zeroo)));
```

And with below code `MapCircle` not added in HERE map

```
MapCircle currentHereMapCircle = null;
currentHereMapCircle = new MapCircle(50.67,mm);
currentHereMapCircle.setRadius(50.67);
currentHereMapCircle.setFillColor(Color.CYAN);
currentHereMapCircle.setLineWidth(2);
currentHereMapCircle.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);
hereMap.addMapObject(currentHereMapCircle);`
```

The app crashes when I add this code, any ideas why?

Comment: post your error log.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: BaseTextureView-RenderThread
                                                                          Process: com.example.hereapi, PID: 6980
                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry
                                                                              at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ag.c(GLMapPolygonDrawable.java:141)
                                                                              at

Comment: after that i add this .jar file  compile files('libs/jts-1.8.jar')    then i got another error      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory.createPolygon
                                                                               at com.here.android.mpa.internal.ag.i(GLMapPolygonDrawable.java:186)

Comment: if your object **mm** is of `GeoCoordinate` and **hereMap** is of `com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map` than your code is perfectly fine. i have tested with HERE SDK 3.3.0

Comment: yes **mm**  is Geo Coordinate  i am using .jar file only from  here map SDK    should i add HERE-sdk  as  module or lib   ..?  i just download new sdk and  replace .jar file    but  got same error    is this is right way to add new HERE-SDK  ...?

Comment: No. New downloaded sdk has `.aar` file so delete JNI folder and old `.jar` file too. Add `.aar` file to libs folder and do like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23326397/3425390).

Comment: Is this the starter edition of the premium edition. JTS should NOT be mandatory for the premium edition.

Comment: well i check that SDK folder but cant find .aar file   my folder    = HERE_Android_SDK_Starter_v3.3.0_30  in this folder i have   ( HERE-sdk , copyright ,one .pdf)  and in HERE-sdk  folder  (libs , tutorial , user-guide  , progurd-here.sdk   )..............

Comment: @kushal I m using premium sdk. I dont know about starter sdk...so ask to David Leong.

Comment: ops its working now with premium sdk   Thanks @Akash Patel

Comment: welcome..... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code that adds a MapCircle to a map:

```
MapCircle circle = new MapCircle(400.0, m_map.getCenter());
circle.setLineColor(Color.BLUE);
circle.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);
circle.setLineWidth(12);
m_map.addMapObject(circle);
```

Check the full implementation at:
https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/map-objects

Comment: What is 400.0 value in MapCircle? Also is it in meters? Is it possible to drag and drop MapCircle in the map anyway?