# Merge multiple completed android project into a single app

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, android-library

I have multiple completed android studio project and I want to combine them into a single android project. The final app should have various tab, and when I click on the different tab button, the tab should bring me to the different projects that I have build individually.

**I have searched and I saw methods such as using library and modules? I am quite lost as I am not sure which is the direction I should follow. Any suggestions?**

Comment: Import modules in your new project.
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html

Comment: In addition to the above you'll need to create an activity with a tab layout and for each tab start the entry point of each project

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you to build projects as `.aar` as well. which is an Android library. [[ This ]](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582) shall help you with creating libraries in Android.

Then the next step is to include all these libraries inside your main App. For that, [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919810/4904608) shall help you.

Comment: I have a question, after i compile and imported the required projects as libraries, can i edit the library if there are any last min changes?

Comment: **Nope** . You can't . Make all the necessary changes inside the libraries itself. One Alternative is You can create normal classes inside the library, then create classes that extend the base classes from the library to add custom features.

Comment: because my application requires a constant change of IP address( as i am using local host), so i would need to edit my mainactivity before i compile every time. Would it still be possible?

Comment: Which IP address are you talking about?

Comment: IPV4 of my computer. And it changes everytime