# Importing newest Google play services to Android NDK Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, android-ndk, google-play-services

I'm implementing Google_play_services to Android (C++) game using Visual Studio, VisualGDB and Android NDK. I Managed to do initialization:

```
extern "C" jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
    {
        Logger::log("JNI_OnLOAD");
        gpg::AndroidInitialization::JNI_OnLoad(vm);
        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    }
```

but I can't add google play services libs as shown here

https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/gettingStartedAndroid

because google_play_services since version 22 doesn't contain

**"/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject",**

Instead there are multiple libraries in

**"/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms"**

I already tried to download version 22 and just copy google-play-services.jar file which i found to the libs directory of my project. But it gives these errors. I assume i need to import newest version. But how to do this?

This are the errors I get

[output with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moSSf.png)

Comment: Each subdirectory of `extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms` contains a bunch of versions of that library. Pick the version you want, and build with the corresponding .aar file.

Comment: how can we add .aar to project?

Comment: Depends on how you're building. If you're using Gradle, then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst  If you're using some other build system, then I don't know, but googling _"<your build system> import aar"_ might help.