# How to include .aar in react native android build?

Tags: android, react-native

I would like to import for example `statusgo-android-16.aar` in android react native project. when I import the .aar file.I have the following error.

Here's what I'm seeing after run react-native run-android:

```
build file 'D:\react-native-starter-app\android\app\build.gradle': 3:
unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
@ line 3, column 1.
import com.android.build.OutputFile
^

1 error.
```

Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: how did you add the `aar` file? and what does your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: Right clicked on the project > Open Module Setting  > Import .Jar /AAR Package >. build.gradle like ```compile 'statusgo-android-16.aar '```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst