# No versions of org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android are available

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, dependencies

I am creating an Android Studio Project that uses tensorflow for image recognition, but suddenly the gradle console prompt an error in the following line:

```html
compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
```

The error is this one:

```html
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any matches for org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+ as no versions of org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android are available.
```

Is this a problem from the Tensorflow servers? or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

(Duplicate of [Tensorflow: not resolving in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694564/tensorflow-not-resolving-in-gradle/46704448#46704448))

Please also see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13653#issuecomment-336145329