# Importing .aar in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not very experienced in Android Studio and I have tried countless ways to solve this issue with no success.

**Goal:** Import an `.aar` file as a library into an Android Studio app.

**Problem:**

1. I have a .aar file (product_test-debug.aar)
2. I imported it into an Android Studio empty app, using:

   - File → New Module → Import JAR/AAR Package
3. I already had one issue in this phase, perhaps due to the question mark in the .aar file; after selecting the file, Android Studio studio would tell me it didnt exist. This error mysteriously disapeared so I'll carry on.

[image: a]

4. The .aar file was added. However, when I switch from Android to Project mode, I can see the file still shows a question mark.

[image: b]

[image: c]

5. Ignoring the question mark, I did 3 things next, following a successful guide:

   - In the settings-gradle, I modified the only line to:
     [image: d]
   - In the build.gradle (Module:app), I added the first dependency:
     [image: e]
   - Still in this script, I commented the following line:
     [image: f]
6. After all these steps, I have tried to sync the gradle and it still does not recognize the .aar. These are the errors:

[image: g]

I tried to put the .aar file into the libs folder, and alter this function in build.gradle(Project:MyApplication) to this:

[image: h]

But it doesn't solve anything. I know what I am trying to do is possible because of the guide, but I don't know what I am missing. The guide is this one for reference:

https://medium.com/@ericdejesus/im-getting-this-error-whenever-i-try-to-build-to-project-from-unity-any-idea-how-to-solve-78d5c22a4571

(Btw for context, I am doing this to be able to launch a sample Unity app from an Android activity. In this case, the Unity app is a spinning cube.)

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Did you declare product_test-debug as a module in gradle ?

Comment: This answer works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450829/4409409

Answer (score 0):

The first line of build.gradle in `product_test-debug` should be :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And add `:path` in build.gradle of app :

```
compile project(path: ':product_test-debug')
```

Comment: Hi Dany,
I am trying to achieve the same thing.
I can import it successfully.
But I am not able to use it.

When I use the class it says `cannot find symbol`