# IntelliJ Android Studio cannot import aar as new module

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I tried to create a new module by importing an aar file but IntelliJ has been stopping me doing so. Cannot click through the "Finish" button. What's the problem?[image]

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919810/5110595) instruction.

Comment: I tried. Didn't work. The window shown above cannot be completed by clicking "Finish", therefore it blocks my next move.

Comment: ok so may be  import aar file not in proper format. try to add another aar file and check it again.