# Gradle compile to implmentation

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, aar

I recently updated my android studio to latest and it install gradle 4.4. After update, my project pop up errors asking to change compile to implementation and I did. But I don't know how to change local android archive resource in library to control special hardware in my app. My case is similar to this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326397/1712016). But **I am trying to migrate to newer gradle version**. this is how it goes.

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
   compile(name: 'MyLibrarySdk_1.0.0', ext: 'arr')
}
```

Following is errors:

```
> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
```

I have tried this code.

```
    implementation(name:'MyLibrarySdk_1.0.0', ext: 'arr')
```

I got following error.

```
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor303.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\phone\Desktop\AndroidProjects\SanbotWebLink\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:109)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:76)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:67)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:107)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:77)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    ... 55 more
```

I notice that after gradle change, it can sync successfully but it failed at compilation. There is one more android issue as follows.

```
Program type already present: kotlin.AutoCloseableKt
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
kotlin.AutoCloseableKt, sources=[Unknown source file], tool 
name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

How can i change compile to implementation? Please help me out.

I found out that issue causing this error is from kotlin. I am not really sure what is the root cause though. After I change back to standard project, it successfully compile

Comment: replace the string `compile` in `dependencies` section to string `implemenation`

Comment: and what it is the issue?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I added my error.

Answer (score 0):

Add this option to your app `build.gradle` file, this works for me in my project

```
android {
    // ...
    dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    // ...
}
```