# why aar importing not happy in android studio?

Tags: android

not duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst) because the `.gradle` files was already configured as suggested.(Note, it's not that I can't build the project but the IDE fail to identify the importing)

---

Newbie to android development

I am using the latest android studio (v3.1.3)

I have download source from a site and try to run that on an android device, which is successful, ie, I could build the apk but in android studio IDE, the import class shows error, the class seems imported from an `aar` file.

How to make the importing work(not showing error) in IDE?

[image]

And here is the `build.gradle` in app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tencent.tmgp.yybtestsdk"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'YSDK_Android_1.3.9_917', ext: 'aar')
}
```

here is the `build.gradle` in project

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you included in your project file in gradle also ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

Comment: @Christopher sine the `.gradle` file was already configured as suggested, I think it's   not a duplicate question, check edit :D

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. So it's compiling, but the Android Studio just shows this errors? Try to perform the usual cleanup stuff: restart, invalidate caches, close AS, remove .idea folder, restart AS and reimport your project. With 3.1.x AS is getting quite unreliable.

Comment: @Christopher not again~ T_T just do that days ago, but worth a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update your `gradle.build` (in the PROJECT level, not app level) like so.

```
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
            dirs 'libs/app'
            dirs "../app/libs"
        }
```

Try changing

```
compile(name: 'YSDK_Android_1.3.9_917', ext: 'aar')
```

to

```
implementation(name: 'YSDK_Android_1.3.9_917', ext: 'aar')
```

Comment: thanks, but got no luck, trying the clean&restart&remove cache stuff now :(

Comment: if you open that project up in explorer (or finder on mac) where is the folder 'libs' located? is it app>libs?

Comment: can you also try changing the word compile to implemention... ill update my answer.

Comment: also, make sure you change the build.gradle in the project gradle, not the app: gradle

Comment: yeah, after restart AS and clean `.idea` and `.gradle` in the project folder, and upgrade the gradle to 4.4 and change to implemention, things are working now importing is happy :D thanks a lot

Comment: great. happy coding! :)