# Importing PocketSphinx resources into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, pocketsphinx

I am trying to start a project using PocketSphinx resources. What is the method for importing PocketSphinx resources into my Android Studio workspace?

```
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets; //"unused import statement"
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis; //"unused import statement"
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener; //"unused import statement"
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer; //"unused import statement"
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup; //"unused import statement"

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {...
```

As expected, I am getting a, "Cannot resolve symbol 'RecognitionListener' " on the last line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is distributed as an Android Archive (AAR). Download from https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo/blob/master/aars/pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar

Move pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release.aar into helloworld/app/lib/ directory.

In Android Studio go to File > New > New module, scroll down and choose Import .JAR/.AAR Package. Browse to /app/lib and select the .aar file. Click "Okay". Keep the apps module selected, click dependencies tab, click "+" on far right side, choose "Module Dependency". Select Module and click "Okay". For further information go to [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/), scroll to Oliver Kranz's answer for nice screen grabs of the process.

Comment: Additional concise useful information here regarding PS on Android: www.guidearea.com/pocketsphinx-continuous-speech-recognition-android-tutorial/