# How to create configuration APKs for external sdk library added to an android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

I'm using an [external sdk](https://developer.dsphotoeditor.com/) in my android app. Just like my resources, the sdk also has a set of images in multiple dpi folders.
Is there a way to create configutation APKs for these resource while creating an android app bundle (.aab file)

I've tried to create an app bundle and the base-master apk turned out to contain all the resources of the library module.

I've been using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst) to add the external sdk

Is there a workaround to this? or am I missing something here which can split the sdk also?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the sdk I was using is not properly configured for app-bundle configuration split.

I created my own sdk and put in resources there. When I used that sdk in a different anroid app and created app-bundle, android was able to create individual configuration apks for different dpi images. It worked out perfectly fine.