# How to import an .aar library file in a library module and export as single library?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have an .aar library (`libA.aar`) file and a library module. The `.aar` file added to library module in dependencies section (at library module `build.gradle`)(`libB.aar`):

```
implementation files('libs/libA.aar')
```

When I export this library as an .aar file (`libB.aar`) the imported library (`libA.aar`) not found on exported file.

How can I import that `.aar` file in a library and having that in exported file?
Is need to use offline Maven repository?

I need a fat library with all of dependency inside that as an `.aar` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually include external aar package using new Gradle Android Build System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst)

Comment: @alirezadaryani i read that question and is not useful for me,  the exported library file with flat dir does not contain  aar included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **fat aar** for your library with imported aar. Please go through
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-fat-aar-from-gradle-892038facc87

Comment: thanks, the fat aar way solve my problem and the exported aar module has all of libraries inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separately include[copy/paste] all the used .aar libraries into the integrating application as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add your .aar file in **src -> main -> libs** folder

[image: Adding .aar file]

---

Add path in your **build.gradle(Project)** file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir { //Add this code
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}
```

---

Add implementation code in your **build.gradle(app)** file

```
dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'nameOfAARFile', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Comment: The exported library file with flat dir does not contain aar included, how can i fix that?