# Implementing uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5 in build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle, color-picker

I imported the **LeafPic** project and I'm unable to sync the project. The error states that unable to resolve **uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5**. I searched for the web a lot and I couldn't find a solution.

build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.sdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.horaapps.leafpic"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion project.sdkVersion
        versionName "v0.7-alpha-2"
        versionCode 16
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "LeafPic"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "LeafPic (debug)"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        noGPlay {
            dimension "default"
        }

        withGPlay {
            dimension "default"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //exifInterface
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportVersion"

    // google & support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"

    //exo-player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.6.0'

    // utils
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    //surumu 4.7.1 den 4.8.0 ya yukseltildi
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'  //surumu 4.7.1 den 4.8.0 ya yukseltildi
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.github.Commit451:bypasses:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.11.0'
    implementation "com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.4.3'

    // rxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    //it is recommended to keep the same version of rxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'
//    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'

    // icons
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.3@aar'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.0.3@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.2.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.2@aar'

    // ui
    implementation 'uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.jetradarmobile:desertplaceholder:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'
    implementation 'com.github.HoraApps:Liz:-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'


    // debug Only
    //debugCompile project(':inappstoragereader')
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:2.2.0'
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.2' //1.5.4den 1.6.2 yeyukseltildi
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.2'  //1.5.4den 1.6.2 yeyukseltildi

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    // TODO check them out
    implementation 'com.turingtechnologies.materialscrollbar:lib:10.0.3'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.3'
}

Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
```

Displayed error is:

```
Failed to resolve: uz:shiftcolorpicker:0.5
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

[recordnotfound.com states that the issue is 3 years old and it is still marked as an open issue.](https://recordnotfound.com/LeafPic-HoraApps-114771/issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work around i found is to download the aar and import it as module.
You can download the aar from the [github](https://github.com/DASAR/ShiftColorPicker) for the repository or [click here](https://github.com/DASAR-zz/ShiftColorPicker/releases)

Then you can follow the [procedure here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59032151/7414213) to import the module

You should remove dependencies in both build.gradle relating to uz.shift:colorpicker:0.5

Don't forget to add the module/library to your dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
........
implementation project(path: ':colorpicker-0.5')
........
}
```

Then sync your android studio project.

Answer (score 0):

add in project level gradle file:

```
repositories {
     maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven"
     }
}
```

add in app(module) level gradle file:

```
implementation(group: 'uz.shift', name: 'colorpicker', version: '0.5', ext: 'aar')
```

**Edit:**

download the aar file from here and put it in libs folder:
https://bintray.com/dasar/maven/shiftcolorpicker/0.5

add this line in app gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in one of my older apps, seems like it doesn't work with gradle 6.5.

To solve this, I downloaded whole repo from github.
https://github.com/DASAR-zz/ShiftColorPicker

import shiftcolorpicker module in project and in gradle put :

```
 implementation project(path: ':shiftcolorpicker')
```