# tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops and tensorflow-lite AAR built from source tflite model cannot find org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter

Tags: android, tensorflow, build.gradle, tensorflow-lite, aar

I followed tensorflow android guide to generate `tensorflow-lite.aar` and `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar` from source.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_android

My current app works with,

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.3.0'
}
```

**I am looking to reduce size of `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar` to decrease app `apk` size**.

I am following `build_aar.sh` process to reduce size with my tflite model. The command used,

```
bash tensorflow/lite/tools/build_aar.sh --input_models=custom_model.tflite --target_archs=arm64-v8a
```

This generates `tensorflow-lite.aar` and `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar` in `bazel-bin/tmp` folder for `custom_model.tflite`. The tflite model is `FP16` quantized.

Implementation with newly generated aar files,

```
dependencies {
    ...
//    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.3.0'
//    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'

    implementation files('libs/tensorflow-lite.aar')
//    implementation files('libs/tensorflow-lite-gpu.aar')
    implementation files('libs/tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar')
}
```

But when they are included in android app compilation error occurs.

```
C:\folder\myapp\app\src\main\java\com\example\mapp\tflite\YoloV4Classifier.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Interpreter
  location: package org.tensorflow.lite
```

This problem goes away when `tensorflow-lite.aar` built with `bazel build -c opt --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite`. But that introduces **UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol** with previous `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar` and newly built `tensorflow-lite.aar` with above command.

If I put both previous `tensorflow-lite.aar` generated from `custom_model.tflite` and new `tensorflow-lite.aar` generated with `bazel build -c opt --fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain tensorflow/lite/java:tensorflow-lite` then there is build error,

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so'
```

I followed non input tflite model based command to generate `tensorflow-lite.aar`, `tensorflow-lite-gpu.aar`, `tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops.aar` from source, but app size becomes very large. I have tried [other ways](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45153) but each one brings up a new type of error.

Comment: Had some problems adding tflite aars to project, try [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445004/14161847) approach

Comment: Adding AAR is working fine, but the problem is tensorflow-lite built from source cannot find Interpreter.

Comment: I meant that I have experienced same problem (interpreter not found but with normal build) and with that approach worked

Comment: Github issue, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45153.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues were fixed as mentioned below,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45153

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46989

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45488

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line to your dependencies in app-level build.gradle

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.9.0'
```