# importing an existing JAR or AAR as new project module

Tags: android, android-studio, github, sdk, android-developer-api

how to import JAR or   AAR package as new project module in   **A new Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 9** ?

please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.programmersought.com/article/36706527385/

Comment: this worked for me ! follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819440/11973801

Answer (score 13):

This works on Android Studio Arctic Fox Beta 02

Step 1 : Navigate to,  <kbd>File</kbd>  -> <kbd>Project Structure</kbd>. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

You will see a window just like below.

[image]

Step 2 : Click On app module as shown in image

Step 3 : Click on  <kbd>+</kbd>  icon as marked in image

[image]

Step 4 : You will see option to select jar/aar dependency. Click on it

[image]

You will  see another window just like above asking you to specify path. Specify the path in which you kept the aar/jar file and hit Ok.

That should work

Comment: Still can't select aar file from explorer in step 1.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya How about manually copying and pasting the path in that field ?

Comment: after adding it this way, the new module should be manually added to settings.gradle, like this: `include ':modulename'`

Comment: For me I first put the aar file in the `libs` directory, and then the path i needed to specify was "../libs/<nameoffile>.aar".  But overall this was a great answer with helpful screenshots!

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio Bumblebee, original answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72173958/2024527)

I have followed steps suggested by the [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-aar-jar-dependency):

1. Copy .aar file into the libs folder of the app
2. File -> Project Structure... -> Dependencies

[image]

3. Click on "+" icon and select JR/AAR Dependency and select app module

[image]

4. Add .aar file path in step 1.

[image]

5. Check your app’s build.gradle file to confirm a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly implement using JAR/ARR file path.

```
implementation files('/File Path/file.aar')
```

Comment: this is not the question. Need to do it from UI as previous version

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Put your aar file in the libs folder. And let’s take the file name is **supernover.aar** as an example.

**Step 2:** Put the following code in your Project level

```
build.gradle  file,
    allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}
```

and in the app level module write the below code,

```
dependencies {
    Implementation(name:'supernover', ext:'aar')
}
```

**Step 3:** Then Click sync project with Gradle files.

If everything is working fine, then you will see library entry is made in build **->intermediates -> exploded-aar**.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to deploy the jar/aar to a local maven repository. if you install maven, you can use the `mavenLocal()` repository in gradle and read from there as with any other repo, regardless of the IDE you are using. All versions of Android Studio will work, all version of IntelliJ will work, VSCode will work, the command line will work, etc. Another advantage is, you'll be able to swap versions of the library as you do with all the others, just change the version in gradle (after deploying the new one), and will work for all your projects. Putting jars/aars manually into a project is just a bad practice, and reaaally outdated to top.

Once you installed maven, type this in your terminal:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=d:\mylibrary-{version}.aar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mylibrary -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=aar
```

Where you swap `aar` and `jar` depending on the type. The package name, group ID and library name are up to you, anything will work. I would use the library's package and name, and version 1.0 if you don`t have a version.

Here's an example link. Is old, but the process is the same. `mvn install`, then consume from `mavenLocal()`.

Comment: this is not the question. Need to do it from UI as previous version

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in search of a solution still.

1. Create a new android Application project.
2. Convert new project into a standalone Library module.
3. Add `maven-publish` plugin to the module-level `build.gradle`
4. Connect your project to your Github repository (or create a new one).
5. In the module-level `build.gradle`, implement the [Github Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages) authentication flow. I'm using 'zuko' as an example - replace every instance of that name with your Github login.

```
android {
...
  publishing {
       repositories {
           maven {
               name = "GitHubPackages"
               url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/zuko/[git-repository]")
               credentials {
                   username = 'zuko'
                   password = 'token' // this is a Git Personal Access Token
               }
           }
       }

       publications {
           release(MavenPublication) {
               groupId 'com.zuko.libraries'
               artifactId 'choose-a-name'
               version '1.0.0'
               artifact("$buildDir/ogury-mediation-mopub-5.2.0.aar") 
              // you can actually put the artifact anywhere you want.
              // This is the location of where you place your .aar file
           }
       }
   }
...
}
```

6. If everything is connected properly, save your work, and run the the task: `./gradlew publish`. The error logs are straightforward so just defer to the instructions and Google for more assistance.
7. To install a successfully published package into your desired project, use the same auth procedure for `publishing.repositories`, you don't need the second half, `publishing.publications`.
8. example: `implementation 'com.zuko.libraries:choose-a-name:1.0.0`'

Answer (score -1):

You could configure a repository in you `buildscript` that looks for dependencies in a local directory

Use this to register a local directory as repository in your app module's `build.gradle` where `libs` is a directory under app module (`<project>/app/libs/`)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    }
}
```

then declare your dependencies from the local file tree you registered earlier

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}
```

This will include all jar/aar artifacts present under `libs` directory to be included in your module's dependencies.

PS: Local jar/aar artifacts will expect any transitive dependencies to be on the classpath unless they are fat-jars (package all transitive dependencies within the artifact), so these need to be added explicitly as dependencies.

Comment: this is not the question.
Need to do it from UI as previous version.

Comment: since it's a canary version (non-stable) features may not work as expected all the time you could file a bug on their tracker if GUI is broken.


Meanwhile, this might help as a workaround if someone is blocked because of canary release not working properly