# How to import .AAR module on Android Studio 4.2

Tags: android-studio, aar

Previously I used File > New > New Module > Import .JAR/.AAR Package

but the option to Import .JAR/.AAR Package from the New Module wizard has been removed on Android Studio 4.2 and following the document which suggests using the [Project Structure Dialog](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-library-dependency)  reveals no clear answer for importing .AAR module and seems to be outdated

I tried adding the module as a dependency in the project Structure but it did not work

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From Android Studio package manager select **project**:

[image]

Then make a new directory in project level named **libs**

[image]

[image]

Now right click the libs and select **Reveal in finder** and then paste here your .aar file.

[image]
[image]

Now in Build.gradle(Module) add the following implementation.

```
implementation files('../libs/testaarfile.aar')
```

and snyc your project.

Comment: Yes I use this method for adding aar files

Comment: This method usually doesn't work on Flutter plugins, for example. The old way, creating a project works. But could not find it on the new Android Studio 4.2 either.

Comment: Does not work on latest Android Studio as they have changed the layout of the package manager.

Comment: Working perfectly for my Flutter plugin

Comment: 2023: Looks like it is `('libs/testaarfile.aar')`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to add your .aar file as a different module and not as a dependency to the main 'app' module in Android Studio 4.2, You can try the following:

1. Create a new folder in the same directory where your 'app' module is located and name it same as your .aar for example 'MyLib' for 'MyLib.aar'
2. Paste the MyLib.aar file in that directory.
3. Open notepad and type the following:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")

artifacts.add("default", file('MyLib.aar'))
```

and save the file as **build.gradle** in the 'MyLib' folder.

4. In the project level **settings.gradle** file, change the line `include ':app'` to `include ':app', ':MyLib'`
5. In the app module build.gradle, add the following line in the depedencies section

   `implementation project(":MyLib")`
6. Sync the project and do a clean rebuild

Comment: I wish I could offer 1000 upvotes for this answer. In the desperate throes of retrofitting an ancient application, I found myself needing to follow instructions from a repository several years old that required the `Import .JAR/.AAR Package` functionality. This answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

For Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3

I have followed steps suggested by the [Android developer site](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#psd-add-aar-jar-dependency):

1. Copy .aar file into the libs folder of the app
2. File -> Project Structure... -> Dependencies

[image]

3. Click on "+" icon and select JR/AAR Dependency and select app module

[image]

4. Add .aar file path in step 1.

[image]

5. Check your app’s build.gradle file to confirm a declaration.