# Missing "import .jar/aar package" option in add new module

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

Trying to import .aar file into project but cannot find the option of `import .jar/aar package` inside the add new module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your aar/jar file to module "libs" folder ( create "app\libs" folder if not exist )
and add this line to your module Build.gradle file:

```
implementation files('libs/your_lib_name.aar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a project-level "libs" folder. If you have this directory with .aar/.jar files, you can just add a new .aar/.jar file to this folder.

If you don't have this directory, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724530/13556102)

But you can use this:

```
implementation fileTree (dir: "libs", include: ["* .jar", "* .aar"])
```

instead of adding a new file implementation to the gradle every time:

```
implementation files('../libs/testaarfile.aar')
```