# How do you import a package in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, jfugue

I am extremely inexperienced with Android Studio - and am having an issue with my imports. I'm trying to build an app that creates music from an `ArrayList` of "note" objects (I've made this class - it has info on). I am trying to import midi driver (https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver) to play my music, but I keep getting an error when I try to write this:

```
import org.billthefarmer.mididriver;
```

in my code (specifically the Analyzer object I've made - you'll see it in the pic). Here is a pic of my project structure. I've added Midi Driver as a dependency to my build.gradle

```
implementation project(path: ':org.billthefarmer.mididriver')
```

in my app folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm sorry to bother!

Here is the pic of my project structure
[image: Here is the pic of my project structure]

Comment: The real answer here: pick any decent tutorial on Android that discuses the usage of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the specific error message to help others better understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it in `MyApp/app/build.gradle` like this :

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation 'com.github.billthefarmer:mididriver:v1.24'
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to do this without getting it from github with Maven? I have it imported as a module in my project - can I import that? What would be the syntax? I haven't downloaded Maven for Android, which is why I ask.

Comment: Take the aar from the internet and add it to your libs directory then add in dependencies to compile with all .aar of libs as following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326397/5583881