# How we can create a .aar file of library which contains another .aar file in Android. Is there any possible solution

Tags: android, kotlin, maven

What to create an aar file for an android library which contains another .aar dependiency .
When i create aar for my library. Sub aar file not inculude in that .
Any Help

i tried to upload the lib to jetpack but same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually include external aar package using Gradle for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-gradle-for-android)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.